# Does Visual Studio have debug symbols available?

Tags: visual-studio, debug-symbols

I'd like to track down a possible bug in Visual Studio, but that's awfully hard without the debug symbols for Visual Studio itself. Does Microsoft make these available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An up-to-date Visual Studio should already have the option to load symbols from Microsoft (Check: Tools->Options->Debug->Symbols). When it comes to debugging Visual Studio itself, have a look at this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2009/06/08/9711306.aspx).

Comment: in VS2015 it's *Debugging* instead of *Debug*

Answer (score 1):

No, the closest thing are the debug symbols for the libraries which can be downloaded following the the steps [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503).  But like I said, these are not for visual studio itself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, most of the Visual Studio Dlls had symbols in the symbol server. msenv.dll is one of the most important.